# ksoap2 can't call the ItemInfo

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <gos:SetReceiptRow>
     <gos:ReceiptUUID></gos:ReceiptUUID>
     <gos:ItemInfo>
        <gos:RowID></gos:RowID>
        <gos:Price></gos:Price>
     </gos:ItemInfo>
  </gos:SetReceiptRow>
```

i have error when i try to call property to itemInfo

My syntax is :

```
SoapObject item_obj = new SoapObject(Name_Space, "ItemInfo" );
item_obj.addProperty("Quantity",Quantity);
item_obj.addProperty("RowID",RowID);
item_obj.addProperty("Price",Price);

    SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject( Name_Space, Method_Name);
    soapObject.addProperty("ReceiptUUID", ReceiptUUID);
    soapObject.addSoapObject( item_obj );
```

Comment: Which error are you getting ?  What is your expected outcome ?

Comment: Error is :  E/envelope.bodyIn:: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring:

Comment: I try in SoapUI and i have a response. My expected outcome is confirmation if data in web services is added or not .